# Save Tensorflow Compiled Model On Interrupt in Colab

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model that it takes so long to complete the epochs (set to 129). Let's say, I want to intrupt the training but don't want to lose the model.

```
model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_modified, ys, epochs = 127, verbose=1, callbacks=[callbacks] ) # verbose 1 means progress bar
from keras.models import load_model
file_Name = "shahnameh_embdding64_bidirectional_LSTM400_softmax.h5"
model.save(file_Name)
```

I used the callback:

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.models = []
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    try:
      target_acc = .2
      if logs.get('acc') > target_acc:
        print('\nReached '+target_acc+'% accuracy, so cancelling the accuracy')
        self.model.stop_training = True
        models.append(model)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      model = self.models[-1]

callbacks = myCallback()
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> NameError: name 'models' is not defined

Any ideas? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS

Answer (score 0):

It's not interrupt between that line but somewhere else during fit. What about

```
callbacks = myCallback()
try:
    history = model.fit(X_modified, ys, epochs = 127, verbose=1, callbacks=[callbacks] )
except:
    model.save(file_Name)
```

I alway use something like this though